# R - Find x days from start date while keeping dates inbetween

Tags: r, date, sequence, lubridate

I am trying to find the first date of each category then subtract 5 days **AND I want to keep the days inbetween!** this is where I am struggling. I tried *seq()* but it gave me an error, so I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

**I am able to get 5 days prior to my start date for each category,** ***but I can't figure out how to get 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 AND 5 days prior to my start date!***

The error I got is this (for the commented out part of the code):
*Error in seq.default(., as.Date(first_day), by = "day", length.out = 5) :
'from' must be of length 1*

***Any help would be greatly appreciated!***

```
library ("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
data <- data.frame(date = c("2020-06-08",
                            "2020-06-09",
                            "2020-06-10",
                            "2020-06-11",
                            "2020-06-12",
                            "2021-07-13",    
                            "2021-07-14",
                            "2021-07-15",
                            "2021-08-16",
                            "2021-08-17",
                            "2021-08-18",
                            "2021-09-19",
                            "2021-09-20"),
                   value = c(2,1,7,1,0,1,2,3,4,7,6,5,10),
                   category = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4))
data$date <- as.Date(data$date)                      
View(data)
```

[image]

```
test_dates <- data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(1L) %>% #takes first date
  mutate(first_day = as.Date(date) - 5)#%>%
  #seq(as.Date(first_day),by="day",length.out=5)

#error for seq(): Error in seq.default(., as.Date(first_day), by = "day", length.out = 5) : 'from' must be of length 1
head(test_dates)
```

[image]

The answer I'm looking for should include these dates but in a column format! I'm also trying to input NA in the value category if the value doesnt already exist. I want to keep all possible columns, as the dataframe I'm needing to use this on has about 20 columns

Dates: "2020-06-03 ", "2020-06-04", "2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-07", "2020-06-08", "2020-07-08 ", "2020-07-09", "2020-07-10", "2020-07-11", "2020-07-12", "2021-07-13", "2020-08-11 ", "2020-08-12", "2020-08-13", "2020-08-14", "2020-08-15", "2021-08-16", "2020-09-14 ", "2020-09-15", "2020-09-16", "2020-09-17", "2020-09-18", "2021-09-19",

Related question here: [How do I subset my df for the minimum date based on one category and including x days before that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000515/how-do-i-subset-my-df-for-the-minimum-date-based-on-one-category-and-including-x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach provides the row from each category with the minimum date, plus the five dates prior for each category (with value set to `NA` for these rows)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[data[, .(date=seq(min(date)-5,by="day", length.out=6)), category], on=.(category,date)]
```

Output:

```
          date value category
 1: 2020-06-03    NA        1
 2: 2020-06-04    NA        1
 3: 2020-06-05    NA        1
 4: 2020-06-06    NA        1
 5: 2020-06-07    NA        1
 6: 2020-06-08     2        1
 7: 2021-07-08    NA        2
 8: 2021-07-09    NA        2
 9: 2021-07-10    NA        2
10: 2021-07-11    NA        2
11: 2021-07-12    NA        2
12: 2021-07-13     1        2
13: 2021-08-11    NA        3
14: 2021-08-12    NA        3
15: 2021-08-13    NA        3
16: 2021-08-14    NA        3
17: 2021-08-15    NA        3
18: 2021-08-16     4        3
19: 2021-09-14    NA        4
20: 2021-09-15    NA        4
21: 2021-09-16    NA        4
22: 2021-09-17    NA        4
23: 2021-09-18    NA        4
24: 2021-09-19     5        4
          date value category
```

Note: The above uses a join; an identical result can be achieved without a join by row-binding the `first` row for each category with the data.table generated similarly as above:

```
rbind(
  setDT(data)[order(date), .SD[1],category],
  data[,.(date=seq(min(date)-5,by="day",length.out=5),value=NA),category]
)
```

You indicate you have many columns, so if you are going to take this second approach, rather than explicitly setting `value=NA` in the second input to `rbind`, you can also just leave it out, and add `fill=TRUE` within the `rbind()`

A `dplyr` version of the same is:

```
bind_rows(
  data %>% 
    group_by(category) %>%
    slice_min(date) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(date=as.Date(date)),
  data %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    summarize(date=seq(min(as.Date(date))-5,by="day", length.out=5), .groups="drop")
)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 24 x 3
   date       value category
   <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-06-08     2        1
 2 2021-07-13     1        2
 3 2021-08-16     4        3
 4 2021-09-19     5        4
 5 2020-06-03    NA        1
 6 2020-06-04    NA        1
 7 2020-06-05    NA        1
 8 2020-06-06    NA        1
 9 2020-06-07    NA        1
10 2021-07-08    NA        2
# ... with 14 more rows
```

#### Update (9/21/22) -

If you want the NA values to be filled, simply add this to the end of either `data.table` pipeline:

```
 ...[,value:=max(value, na.rm=T), category]
```

or add this to the dplyr pipeline

```
... %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(value=max(value, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Yes! This is very close to what I am looking for! How would I subset the existing data for these dates or add it to a new column in the df?

Comment: see edit - you mean the value should be there as well? NA for new rows, right?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Sorry for this next question but is there an easy way to format your solution with these: "%>%"?

Comment: do you mean using `dplyr` or do you mean simply chaining?

Comment: When I apply this code, specifically this part of it "summarize(date=seq(min(as.Date(date))-5,by="day", length.out=5), .groups="drop")" to a different df, it replaces all the other columns with NAs for alot of those dates (even if they have data in the actual df), is there a way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Yes, the summarize part of the code will always produce a result that only has the summarized columns (plus any grouping columns).  Its sounds like the join approach might be better.  However, I think you might need to show me what you mean - Perhaps post a different question?

Comment: Good idea! I did as you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73000515/how-do-i-subset-my-df-for-the-minimum-date-based-on-one-category-and-including-x Thank you again for all your help.  This is very close!

Comment: I was wondering if you might be interested in a third similar q since you're a magician. No worries if not! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73256134/how-to-filter-data-with-starting-and-ending-conditions

Comment: Is there a way to bring the values over when doing this to avoid NAs? Such as category 1 would be 2 for all the category 1 dates, rather than a single 1 and mostly NAs?

Comment: not sure what you mean. "category 1 would be 2"?  Do you mean `value` would be `2` for all rows where `category` is `1`?

Comment: sorry, I meant the value would be 2 for all rows for category 1

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach but kinda clunky:

```
bind_rows(
  data,
  data %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    slice_min(date) %>%
    uncount(6, .id = "id") %>%
    mutate(date = date - id + 1) %>%
    select(-id)) %>%
  arrange(category, date)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 37 × 3
   date       value category
   <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-06-03     2        1
 2 2020-06-04     2        1
 3 2020-06-05     2        1
 4 2020-06-06     2        1
 5 2020-06-07     2        1
 6 2020-06-08     2        1
 7 2020-06-08     2        1
 8 2020-06-09     1        1
 9 2020-06-10     7        1
10 2020-06-11     1        1
# … with 27 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jon Srpings answer fired this alternative approach:

Here we first get the first days - 5 as already presented in the question. Then we use bind_rows as Jon Srping does in his answer. Next step is to identify the original first dates within the dates column (we use `!duplicated` within `filter`). Last main step is to use `coalesce`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(x = min(ymd(date))-5) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  bind_rows(data) %>% 
  mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(date)) %>% 
  mutate(x = coalesce(x, date)) %>% 
  arrange(category) %>% 
  select(date = x, value)
```

```
   category date       value
      <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
 1        1 2020-06-03     2
 2        1 2020-06-09     1
 3        1 2020-06-10     7
 4        1 2020-06-11     1
 5        1 2020-06-12     0
 6        2 2021-07-08     1
 7        2 2021-07-14     2
 8        2 2021-07-15     3
 9        3 2021-08-11     4
10        3 2021-08-17     7
11        3 2021-08-18     6
12        4 2021-09-14     5
13        4 2021-09-20    10
```