# How do I subset my df for the minimum date based on one category and including x days before that?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter, subset

This is an additional question related to: [R - Find x days from start date while keeping dates inbetween](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72973500/r-find-x-days-from-start-date-while-keeping-dates-inbetween)

- I'm trying to subset my dataframe **to select the first date of each
  category** ***then*** **including the previous 3 days for each**.

Right now, with the help of *langtang* (thank you!), I am very close! however, this gives NA values, rather than subsetting what I already have.

*Note:* Not every row includes their specified category is on purpose, as my giant main df I am applying this to has the same kind of thing

*Reprex below*

Df example:

[image]

What I'm trying to subset, where the minimum date from the categories (colored accordingly) are in bold and the 3 days prior are highlighted for each:

[image]

**My goal end result:**

[image]

Reprex:

```
library ("lubridate")
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
data <- data.frame(Date = c("2020-06-04",
                            "2020-06-05",
                            "2020-06-06",
                            "2020-06-07",
                            "2020-06-08",
                            "2020-07-08",
                            "2020-07-09",
                            "2020-07-10",
                            "2020-07-11",
                            "2020-07-12",
                            "2020-08-10",
                            "2020-08-11",
                            "2020-08-12",
                            "2020-08-13",
                            "2020-08-14",
                            "2020-08-15",
                            "2020-09-13",
                            "2020-09-14",
                            "2020-09-15",
                            "2020-09-16",
                            "2020-09-17",
                            "2020-09-18",
                            "2020-06-09",
                            "2020-06-10",
                            "2020-06-11",
                            "2020-06-12",
                            "2020-07-13",    
                            "2020-07-14",
                            "2020-07-15",
                            "2020-08-16",
                            "2020-08-17",
                            "2020-08-18",
                            "2020-09-19",
                            "2020-09-20",
                            "2020-09-21"),
                   Value = c(5,6,3,2,9,
                             5,8,3,2,9,
                             5,7,3,2,5,
                             2,1,3,2,9,
                             2,1,7,1,0,
                             1,2,3,4,7,
                             6,5,10,13,14),
                   Category = c(0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,
                                0,0,1,1,1,
                                1,3,3,3,5,
                                5,5,7,7,7))
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)                      
View(data)


df <- bind_rows(
  data %>% 
    group_by(Category) %>%
    slice_min(Date) %>% #take the first date of each category
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Date=as.Date(Date)),
  data %>%
    group_by(Category) %>%
    summarize(Date=seq(min(as.Date(Date))-3,by="day", length.out=3), .groups="keep", na.rm = TRUE) #goal is to take the previous 3 days from the first day of each category and keep all rows - right now, it's replacing them with NA values
)


head(df)
```

*edited to show categories might not be all nice and sequential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
firsts_3b <- data %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  slice_min(Date, n = 1) %>%
  filter(Category != 0) %>%
  summarize(Date = Date - (0:3)) %>%
  pull(Date)


data %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  filter(Date %in% firsts_3b)
```

Result

```
         Date Value Category
1  2020-06-06     3        0
2  2020-06-07     2        0
3  2020-06-08     9        0
4  2020-06-09     7        1
5  2020-07-10     3        0
6  2020-07-11     2        0
7  2020-07-12     9        0
8  2020-07-13     2        2
9  2020-08-13     2        0
10 2020-08-14     5        0
11 2020-08-15     2        0
12 2020-08-16     7        3
13 2020-09-16     9        0
14 2020-09-17     2        0
15 2020-09-18     1        0
16 2020-09-19    10        4
```