# How to filter data with starting and ending conditions?

Tags: date, dplyr, filter, group-by, sequence

I'm trying to filter my data based on two conditions dependent on sequential dates.

- I am looking for **values below 2 for 5+ sequential dates**,
- with a *"cushion period"* of **values 2 to 5 for up to *3 sequential days*.**

It would look something like this *(sorry for the terrible excel attempt here)*:

[image]

Day 1 to Day 10 would be included and day 11 would not be. Days 6 to 8 would be considered the "cushion period." I hope this makes sense!!

Right now, *I am able to get the cushion period* (in the reprex) only but I cant figure out how to add the **start and ending condition** **for values under 2 for *5 sequential dates*** to be included (*the 5 days could be broken up with the cushion period inbetween but I feel like this might complicate things*).

**Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!**

For my reprex (*below*), the dates that would be included in the final df are in blue (dates from 1/1/2000 to 1/9/2000, and 1/22/2000 to 1/30/2000) and the dates in grey would not be.

[image]

Reprex:

```
    library("dplyr")
#Goal: include all values with values of 2 or less for 5 consecutive days and allow for a "cushion" period of values of 2 to 5 for up to 3 days
data <- data.frame(Date = c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-06", "2000-01-07", "2000-01-08", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-11", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-13", "2000-01-14", "2000-01-15", "2000-01-16", "2000-01-17", "2000-01-18", "2000-01-19", "2000-01-20", "2000-01-21", "2000-01-22", "2000-01-23", "2000-01-24", "2000-01-25", "2000-01-26", "2000-01-27", "2000-01-28", "2000-01-29", "2000-01-30"),
               Value = c(2,3,4,5,2,2,1,0,1,8,7,9,4,5,2,3,4,5,7,2,6,0,2,1,2,0,3,4,0,1))

head(data)                   
#Goal: values should include dates from 1/1/2000 to 1/9/2000, and 1/22/2000 to 1/30/2000

#I am able to subset the "cushion period" but I'm not sure how to add the starting and ending conditions for it
attempt1 <- data %>% 
  group_by(group_id = as.integer(gl(n(),3,n()))) %>% 
  filter(Value <= 5 & Value >=3) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group_id)

head(attempt1)
```

Comment: is 13 through 18 not included because it doesn't have at least one string of 5 consecutive days with values <=2?  That is, there are 6 consecutive days there that within the cushion or lower, but it seems like you require that there must be that consecuttive string of 5 below the cushion, correct?

Comment: yes that is the idea! I want the 5 consecutive days under = or < 2 to be the primary definition, with the up to 3 day cushion period up to 5 as secondary. If this makes it impossible, then we could change it

Comment: What happens if the sequence of cushion period is more than 3?

Comment: if the cushion period is more than 3, it shouldnt be included :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it correctly, you need to keep groups of consecutive values that are below or equal to 5 with at least 5 consecutive values below or equal to 2 within it. Here's a way to do that, with some explanation:

```r
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(under_three = Value <= 2) %>% 
  # under_three = TRUE if Value is below or equal to 2

  group_by(rl_two = data.table::rleid(Value <= 2)) %>%
  # Group by sequence of values that are under_three

  mutate(big = n() >= 5 & all(under_three)) %>%
  # big = T if there are more 5 or more consecutive values that are below or equal to 2  

  group_by(rl_five = data.table::rleid(Value <= 5)) %>% 
  # ungroup by rl_two, and group by rl_five, i.e. consecutive values that are below or equal to 5

  filter(any(big))
  # keep from the data frame groups of rl_five if they have at least one big = T; remove other groups.
```

Output:

```r
data %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(Date, Value)

   Date       Value
 1 2000-01-01     2
 2 2000-01-02     3
 3 2000-01-03     4
 4 2000-01-04     5
 5 2000-01-05     2
 6 2000-01-06     2
 7 2000-01-07     1
 8 2000-01-08     0
 9 2000-01-09     1
10 2000-01-22     0
11 2000-01-23     2
12 2000-01-24     1
13 2000-01-25     2
14 2000-01-26     0
15 2000-01-27     3
16 2000-01-28     4
17 2000-01-29     0
18 2000-01-30     1
```